# Pymongo dict element in array output

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, bottle

I got a database with this info:

```
{"_id":1, "test":6,"foo":[{"mom":5,"dad":10},{"mom":7, "dad":12}]}
{"_id":2, "test":9,"foo":[{"mom":6,"dad":20},{"mom":7, "dad":15}]}
{"_id":3, "test":10, "foo":[{"mom":10,"dad":13},{"mom":2, "dad":19}]}
```

and i query in mongo from db with mom=7:

```
cursor = foo.find({"foo.mom":7},{"foo.$":1,"_id":0, "test":1})
for key in cursor:
    print key
```

it prints me this:

```
{"test":6,"foo":[{"mom":7, "dad":12}]}
{"test":9,"foo":[{"mom":7, "dad":15}]}
```

if i use

```
print key['test']
```

i'll get the result of only "test"

So, the question is: how can i get the result like this:

```
{"test":6,"foo":[{"dad":12}]}
{"test":9,"foo":[{"dad":15}]}
```

i tried to use

```
print key["foo.dad"]
```

but it only returns an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the value of "foo" is saved in an array, you need to use key['foo'][0]['dad'] to print the value of 'dad' from the result.

The code I used is like this:

```
cursor = foo.find({"foo.mom":7},{"foo.$":1,"_id":0, "test":1})
for key in cursor:
    print key
    print key['test']
    print key['foo'][0]['dad']
```

And the result I got is like this:

```
{u'test': 6.0, u'foo': [{u'dad': 12.0, u'mom': 7.0}]}
6.0
12.0
{u'test': 9.0, u'foo': [{u'dad': 15.0, u'mom': 7.0}]}
9.0
15.0
```

If you want to get the result without the 'mom' field:

```
{"test":6,"foo":[{"dad":12}]}
{"test":9,"foo":[{"dad":15}]}
```

you can use the aggregation framework:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$foo" },
    { $match : { "foo.mom" : 7 }}, 
    { $project : { 
          _id : 0,
          test : 1,
          "foo.dad" : "$foo.dad"
    }}, 
])
```

And the result is:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "test" : 6,
            "foo" : {
                "dad" : 12
            }
        },
        {
            "test" : 9,
            "foo" : {
                "dad" : 15
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```